# Virtualenv myenv doesn't create virtual environment on exFAT hard drive on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am learning Django with python 3.6. I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS which is also new for me. My pip version is 9.0.1. My problem is when I try to create virtual environment on my external exFAT had drive with **virtualenv myenv** command it gives the error that I shared bellow. But I can create virtual environment on the Desktop with the same command. The problem is very weird for me. I can't solve the problem. Can you guys please help me? Thanks in advance!

**SAMPLE CODE: ERROR**

```
c@p:/media/c/2NDTB/testpro$ virtualenv myenv
Using base prefix '/usr'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/c/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 417, in copyfile
    os.symlink(os.path.realpath(src), dest)
OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented: '/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu' -> '/media/c/2NDTB/testpro/myenv/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/c/.local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/c/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 831, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "/home/c/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1106, in create_environment
    install_python(home_dir, lib_dir, inc_dir, bin_dir, site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink)
  File "/home/c/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1390, in install_python
    copy_required_files(stdlib_dir, lib_dir, symlink)
  File "/home/c/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1300, in copy_required_files
    copyfile(join(src_dir, fn), join(lib_dir, fn), symlink)
  File "/home/c/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 420, in copyfile
    copy_file_or_folder(src, dest, symlink)
  File "/home/c/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 398, in copy_file_or_folder
    shutil.copytree(src, dest, symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 359, in copytree
    raise Error(errors)

shutil.Error: [('/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so', '/media/c/2NDTB/testpro/myenv/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so', "[Errno 38] Function not implemented: '../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1' -> '/media/c/2NDTB/testpro/myenv/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so'"), ('/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6.so', '/media/c/2NDTB/testpro/myenv/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6.so', "[Errno 38] Function not implemented: '../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1' -> '/media/c/2NDTB/testpro/myenv/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6.so'")]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jwpfox for editing my content for a clean read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems in what you are trying to do. The first, smaller problem is that FAT doesn't implement symlinks and virtualenvs by default use symlinks to that version of python they have been created with. You can try `virtualenv --always-copy` to avoid symlinks.

But then you get to the second, bigger problem You're trying to create a virtualenv on a removable drive to port it somewhere. That doesn't work — virtualenvs are not relocatable. When you need a virtualenv at a different place you have to recreate it. To copy the list of installed packages from one virtualenv to another run this in the original virtualenv:

```
pip freeze >requirements.txt
```

then move file `requirements.txt` to the other place, create a new virtualenv and restore packages:

```
virtualenv venv2
source venv2/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Your solution has worked like magic. I have just added the virtual environment folder name myenv at the end of your recommended command like "virtualenv --always-copy myenv". And it's now activated on my 2TB exFAT external hard drive. Thanks a lot buddy phd. Have a great day!